# Initializing Variable Only Once in Matlab Recursive Function

Tags: matlab, recursion

Is there any way to initialize a variable within a recursive Matlab function **only** the first time the function is called?

The function calls itself multiple times within the function and I want to set a variable `d=0` at the very start of the function, and immediately after I want to set `d=d+1`.

Every subsequent time the function is called I want `d=d+1`. I want to initialize the variable inside of the function, and also I don't want to pass it as a parameter of the function.

I get the feeling I need to declare a global variable however I still can't figure out how to do so without changing it's value back to 1 every time the function is called.

Comment: So you're trying to count the number of recursive calls?

Answer (score 0):

> immediately after I want to set `d=d+1`.

Then where does it get used?

My experience with problems like this suggest that either I'm doing something wrong or that there's a better way.

Declaring the variable **persistent** will remember the value over successive calls.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is with as `persistent` declaration. That would look like this:

```
function
    persistent d
    if isempty(d) %this is only true for the first call to the function
        d=0;
    end
    d = d + 1;

    %more function here
end
```

This effectively becomes a counter describing the number of times the function had been called.

That said, passing `d` as parameter send much more elegant to me, although I cannot put my finger on why.

There is a small performance hit to the `persistent` call. At least one that has been my performance bottleneck. Although fit most applications this will not be important.